# How to fix P0335 and P0727 error codes for Cadillac Catera 2000?

Tags: dtc, cadillac, code

Make: Cadillac

Model: Catera

Engine: 3.0L

Year: 2000

Error codes: P0335,P0727

Knowledge level: I know little about cars

Help needed: Please help me find out what is going on and how to fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry, industrial devices like Car Computer Control Systems are out of scope for SuperUser.

Comment: Both faults point to the crankshaft position sensor, as the engine speed is measured by the same sensor. Did you inspect it's wiring, check whether it operates properly or attempt to replace it?

Comment: Do you have a DVOM? The crankshaft sensor put's out a 2v AC signal, backprobe the sensor connector and check output voltage when cranking.